# Oculus DK2 Installation Error

Tags: installation, oculus

It is my post from Oculus forum because I have no answer there.

I have DK2 and I try to install Oculus Setup from https://www.oculus.com/en-us/setup/ and I got error with following message: "Sorry, we encountered an error during installation. Please restart your computer and try running Oculus Setup again".

I found some solutions but it does no work for me: I have the newest NVidia driver (checked and installed using NVidia Experience), I turned off my antivirus, change permissions in regedit (and later try delete Oculus registry keys), check if Oculus directory in AppData is empty, logged in as an Admin and reboot computer. It does not work.

I attached [log file](https://15254b2dcaab7f5478ab-24461f391e20b7336331d5789078af53.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/oculus.vanillacommunities.com/editor/kg/19i403lmcrd3.log) as to link to Oculus forum. It is in my language, but error "Katalog nie jest pusty" means "Directory is not empty".

I works on Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

There's a line which reads:
Scheduling delete of 'C:\OculusSetup-DownloadCache-c3b6f7cb-07f6-40f1-ba02-cc172fcd35a4' on next reboot.

It looks like it's having trouble cleaning up from the failed install. I'd reboot and if that directory is still there manually delete it. You might also want to right click on the installer and select "run as administrator" in case it's a permissions related thing.

Answer (score 0):

If uninstalling (and reinstalling) doesn't work, try modifying the registry as follows:

```
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node 

    [Right Click] and select [Permissions].
    set [Full Control] privileges for the current user for installation.
```